# How close is Hbase/Hive to a major RDBMS?

Tags: hbase, hive

I am looking at Hbase for a schema-less user action store ("user x viewed y", "user x viewed y from page z").

HBase seems a great choice as it

1. stores data in schema-less format, as well as,
2. can support complex queries like an RDBMS

Yes, performance considerations come later.

---

**Question 1:** What features of an RDBMS will I **miss** if I use HBase?

If I used an RDBMS, I would use features like SUM, WHERE, GROUP BY, ORDER, BETWEEN, comparisons and (inner) joins; and upto 2NF normalization. Nothing more complex.

---

**Question 2:** Apart from the querying, what about:

- altering schema
- single step backup of the entire cluster
- master-slave replication and clustering (sorry, this may be more of a Hadoop question, but HBase overview treats it separately)

that are straightforward on an RDBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HBase is very far from an RDBMS. Hive lets your write Map/Reduce jobs with SQL-ish syntax but these are still map/reduce jobs.

From your expectations it sounds you should look at sharding solutions over regular RDBMS eg. [ScaleDB](http://www.scaledb.com/) or [ScaleBase](http://www.scalebase.com/)